# Android Studio : Remove all System.out.println() in a file?

Tags: android, android-studio, ide, keyboard-shortcuts, println

I have used many System.out.println() for debugging purpose which i know isn't a very good idea. Now I want to remove all the print statements without doing it manually.

Is there really any shortcut or trick to achieve this using Android Studio?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To delete all occurences of `System.out.println("...");` you can use the Find&Replace:

Just open the dialog with one of the following shortcuts:

```
Ctrl+Shift+R on Windows
Cmd+Shift+R on Mac OS X
```

Then you can search for the following phrase and just leave "Replace with" empty. (Don't forget to enable regular expressions)

```
System.out.println(.*);
```

Then just press "find" and "Replace"

Your dialog should look like this:

[image]

Comment: And how can this be done for all kinds of *Log* statements?

Comment: You can use this phrase to find Log Messages (e.g. Log.i("hey", "ho");): `Log\..(.*,.*);`

Comment: Thanks for your time :)

Comment: I am not aware the regular expressions can be used here. Removed 300+ print statements in one go :D Thank you. :)

Comment: Hi.. if the statement is in single line,It is working .Thanks for this solution.But if the statement is in more than one line.it is not detecting.for that any way to remove sout?

Comment: You can use the following line in Search and Replace: ``System.out.println([\s\S]*);``

Answer (score 2):

replace with empty or comment that System.out.println()

I think the shortcut that you're looking for is:

```
Ctrl+Shift+R on Windows

Cmd+Shift+R on Mac OS X
```

select **whole project** in **scope** (screenshot attached)

**[[image: 1]]**

Comment: he asked "without doing it manually", imho your solution is mostly manually^^

Answer (score 0):

Use ProGuard:

```
-assumenosideeffects class System {
    public static *** out.println(...);
}
```

Also check that your ProGuard-file is executed when build.

For further information read the [docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html).